# Getting 404 on calling Spring RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a mvn-project containing two modules:

- Server: a spring application providing several REST endpoints.
- Client: angularJS.

Building the war.file all resources generated by npm are copied inside the WebContent folder of the server part. Installing the war-file manually in tomcat does not work. The app is installed without any exceptions, but I get a 404 when I call one of my rest services. AngularJs starts well.

Using Spring is declared inside *WEB-INF/web*

```
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>
             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
         </servlet-class>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
             <param-value>classpath*:spring.xml</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/pmt/*</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

spring.xml config file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="de.pmt.server" />

<!--Services-->
<bean name="releaseService" 
    class="de.pmt.server.release.ReleaseService" p:releaseDAO-ref="releaseDAO"/>
<bean name="estimateService"
    class="de.pmt.server.strategy.EstimateService" />
<bean name="holidayService" 
    class="de.pmt.server.holiday.HolidayService" 
    p:restTemplate-ref="restTemplate" p:holidayDAO-ref="holidayDAO"/>

<!--RestController-->
<bean name="employeeController" 
    class="de.pmt.server.rest.controller.EmployeeController" 
    p:employeeDAO-ref="employeeDAO" />
<bean name="holidayController" 
    class="de.pmt.server.rest.controller.HolidayController" 
    p:holidayService-ref="holidayService"/>
<bean name="vacationController" 
    class="de.pmt.server.rest.controller.VacationController" 
    p:employeeDAO-ref="employeeDAO" p:vacationDAO-ref="vacationDAO" />
<bean name="releaseController" 
    class="de.pmt.server.rest.controller.ReleaseController" 
    p:releaseService-ref="releaseService"/>
<bean name="strategyController" 
    class="de.pmt.server.rest.controller.StrategyController" 
    p:strategyDAO-ref="strategyDAO" />
```

The EmployeeController - as a example - looks like this:

```
package de.pmt.server.rest.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    GenericDAO<Employee> employeeDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/getAll")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
        return employeeDAO.getAll();
    }

}
```

I get the 404 when i call
**localhost:8080/pmt/employee/getAll**

Comment: Is this a legacy project or a new one?

Comment: try replacing  <url-pattern>/pmt/*</url-pattern> with  <url-pattern>/pmt/**</url-pattern> and restart your server

Comment: Are you sure that it's the controller who listens this to link? Maybe Spring data repository interferes?

Comment: First I  had the server part as a single project working on tomcat (8080) and angulars as client on a different server (4200). The Rest-Services were accessable but I had problems with CORS. So I merged them to one project. Since then they don't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should define what type of HTTP method your controller is using (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE)

```
@RequestMapping("/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
    return employeeDAO.getAll();
}
```

Comment: @RequestMapping("/getAll") will support both post and get request.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **@ResponseBody** from your rest controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/getAll" , method = RequestMethod.GET)   
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
        return employeeDAO.getAll();
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't matter with 404 error response body will show the response content in browser window instead of delivering views.